# hard problem in sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I know that $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are adjacent sequences , the problem is in $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and ofc $P_n=2^n$

Comment: Heard about [Brent–Salamin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm)?

Comment: still what is your question?

Comment: ooh , i'm reading about it right now 
i didn't know it is a famous problem , thank you

Comment: my question is how to find the limit

Answer (score 1):

The presented successions show how [Brent-Salamin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm) is mathematically implemented.

In particular $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to the same value limit value and

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{(a_n + b_n)^2}{4t_n} = \pi
$$